# Is *grandmother* a compound?

Tags: morphology, grammar, word-formation, analysis

"*Grand* is used in a specialized sense in kin terms like *grandmother* or *grandson* to indicate a further degree of lineal distance beyond that expressed in the head. Such forms can themselves be modified by *great* (with the same meaning) in a morphological construction that is recursive: there is no linguistic limit on how many *great*'s are permitted in compounds like *great-great-great-grandmother*." (G.K.Pullum & R. Huddlestone, 2002)

The example is very good explained, however, what I could not understand is if we should consider the word *grandmother* as a compound or not. Since *grand* is attached to other bases, I thought that the option to consider *grand* as a prefix should not be avoided.

Comment: It's stress on the "grand" part is consistent with its being a compound.  But sometimes it's shortened to "gram" -- I can't think of any compounds that are similarly shortened. And even in a careful pronunciation, I would not pronounce the "d" in the full form.  I think it's a simple word.

Comment: Yes, it's an adjective+noun compound: grand+mother. The fact that the first base occurs in other compounds is irrelevant, cf. "blacksmith", "blackbird".

Answer (score 0):

Grandmother is indeed a a [compound word](http://www.english-for-students.com/Compound-Words-G.html) coming from the French [grandmère](https://www.etymonline.com/word/grandmother).

[Grand](https://www.etymonline.com/word/grand-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) means

> a generation older than

More or less a generation removed from

Therefore the compound would translation

> A generation older than mother

Comment: Consider "grandson": it doesn't mean "a generation older than". It means "another generation removed", as OP said. Be that as it may, wouldn't it be more felicitous to analyse it as a bound morpheme, which is productive only in a certain semantic field?